# React / Redux: mapStateToProps() is called many times

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm writing simple app using React / Redux. I notice that function mapStateToProps() is called many times. Here`s code:

```
class Employees extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchEmployees();
    }
}

let mapStateToProps = function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("foo");
    return {...};
};

let mapDispatch = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchEmployees: bindActionCreators(fetchEmployees, dispatch)
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatch)(Employees);
```

And what I get in console:

[image]

Is it normal or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: This is normal. That's why for heavy computations in state to props people use memoised selectors, like `reselect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime there is a change in state of redux or the parent component of your container re-renders the `mapStateToProps` is being called. This however won't cause your component's render to call again provided the data returned by mapStateToProps and the props that it receives hasn't changed.

If you have some computation that you do in `mapStateToProps` that returns a value, make sure you use a memoized function to do that computation or `reselect` to write `memoized selectors` so that the same value is returned for the same computation even if `mapStateToProps` is called multiple times

Comment: thanks a lot! Yes, actually I call filter function in `mapStateToProps`. Does this mean I need to use `reselect` to prevent the filter function from being called too many times?

Comment: you can choose to use reselect if you have a lot of such computation that you perform for your app, or if there are just a few, you can choose to implement a custom memoized function yourself. You can find a lot of resources to implement memoization online